# C# CMDlet using Mage

Tags: c#, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to create application and deployment manifest files for a clickonce application. I wrote a C# cmdlet that does the following using mage

I call mage command inside the C# cmdlet with ProcesssStartInfo
1. Create application manifest file - successfully created.
2. Sign the application manifest file - success
3. Create Deployment Manifest file - It seems to be OK but I do not see the file created nor do I see errors.
4. Sign deployment manifest file - No Errors saying did not find the file.

My question is why am I not seeing the deployment manifest file even though it seems to have created the file but with no evidence. The next step signing the deployment manifest file also does not fail. In fact I tried to sign the file, it gave me an error as expected saying the file does not exist

I copied the same code and ran as console application it successfully created the deployment manifest file and signed it too.

Does anyone have similar problem where the deployment manifest file does not get created but no warnings or errors at the same time?

Comment: have you tried to elevate your cmdlet?

Comment: Yes, I did. Funny part is following step of Signing works also, but I if I do the tep of signing manually then I get the error " FIle not found", I thought it might have put the file somewhere else so I searched for the file too to see no existence of the file. Deployment file seems to be invisible :)